# What is x in the following image?

Tags: geometry

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LibJx.jpg)

This shows a right triangle composed of two right triangles with sides of length 32 and 2o. What is the length of side x, and how did you find the solution?

Comment: Hint: There are 3 similar triangles in the picture.

Comment: Please don't tag algebraic-geometry for this, and I think image posts are discouraged. Besides that, what have you tried?

Comment: Try showing triangles are similar . And take advantage of similar triangles

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be the height.

Reflect the triangle about its hypotenuse, you get a kite.

Since the opposite angles are supplementary, the kite is cyclic.

By Intersecting Chord Theorem,

$$h^2=32\times 20$$

By Pythagoras' Theorem,

$$h^2+32^2=x^2$$

$$x=\sqrt{32\times 20+32^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For right angled triangle ACB, applying Pythagoras formula

$(AC)^2=(AB)^2-(BC)^2$

$(AC)^2=x^2-(32)^2$ .....(1)

In right angled triangle ACD, applying Pythagoras formula

$(AD)^2=(AC)^2+(CD)^2$

On putting the value of $(AC)^2$ from equation (1)

$(AD)^2=x^2-(32)^2+(20)^2$

$(AD)^2=x^2-1024+400$

$(AD)^2=x^2-624$ .....(2)

Now, in right angled triangle BAD, applying Pythagoras formula

$(BD)^2=(AB)^2+(AD)^2$

ON putting the value of $(AD)^2$ from equation (2)

$(BC+CD)^2=x^2+x^2-624$

$(32+20)^2=x^2+x^2-624$

$(52)^2=2x^2-624$

$2704=2x^2-624$

$2704+624=2x^2$

$\dfrac{3328}{2}=x^2$

$1664=x^2$

Taking square root on both sides

$\sqrt{1664}=\sqrt{x^2}$

$\sqrt{64\times26}=x$

$8\sqrt{26}=x$

or $x=8\sqrt{26}$

or $x=40.7921$